# Chrome: Pin tabs reopening on startup even after unpinned

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

This chrome function is too weird to me, sometimes I pin a tab, restart the browser and the tab isn't there, other times it is there FOREVER!

The default startup setting in my chrome is to open the "New Tab" tab, but it still reopens the pinned tabs. Now, this is not the problem, the problem is that even after I unpin a tab, it keeps reopening on startup.

Why does this happen? How do I get rid of those pinned tabs?

Chrome version: 47.0.2526.106 m
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a little late but I was having the same problem!

To fix the problem I had to:

1. Uninstall Google Chrome
2. Delete the Chrome folder in C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Local\Google

[image: AppData Folder]

Note: If you don't delete the chrome folder you will still have the problem when you reinstall chrome.

Comment: This is a nuke solution, yet I couldn't find any other way to solve it, so I'm marking as solved with this one.

Answer (score 0):

- Close Chrome
- Under `C:\Users\{YOUR_USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`, you'll find a sub-folder `Profile 1` (and maybe 2 or even more)
- In that folder, remove all files (not the sub-folders) except `Bookmarks` and `Shortcuts`
- Restart Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by unpinning the tabs and instead of pressing the little "x" to close them individually, I closed Chrome completely by clicking the big "x" in the top right corner. I reopened Chrome as usual, and they were gone.